# How to save Jquery click event to local storage to hide css for a specific period

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not good with Javascript and would appreciate any help here.
I have a written a css that display announcement when webpage loads up with a close button to hide the entire css and its contents using Jquery animate.

I would like to use localstorage to keep it hidden once clicked till after a specific period of time, lets say 24hrs, so that when user reloads page, it doesn't show till after the specified period of time.

My code is

```js
$('.cta-floating_close').click(function() {
    $('.cta-floating_component').each(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '-200px',
            }, 500 ); 
    });
});
```

```css
.cta-floating_component {
  position: fixed;
  left: auto;
  top: 9rem;
  right: 2rem;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  max-width: 16rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#b671e4), to(#f01486));
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #b671e4, #f01486);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.cta-floating_close {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  top: -7px;
  right: 0rem;
  bottom: auto;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cta-floating {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta-floating"><div class="cta-floating_component" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; display: block; opacity: 0.9;"><font color="white">Annoucement appears here!</font><div class="cta-floating_close">X<i class="las la-times-circle"></i></div></div></div>
```

How do i implement this? Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `close click`, you can set the time until it should be hidden to the `localStorage`.
In this example it's basically `now` plus 10 seconds (adjust how you need it).

Then `setInterval` to periodically check if that time has been reached or not.

The same on `$(document).ready` in case the viewer has left the page and came back again.

```js
    $('.cta-floating_close').click(function() {
        const now = new Date();
        let then = new Date();
        then.setTime(now.getTime()+ (10*1000)); //10 seconds

        localStorage.setItem('showAt', then);
        setInterval(ShowButton, 1000)


    $('.cta-floating_component').each(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '-200px',
            }, 500 ); 
    });
    
});

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    console.log('ready')
        ShowButton()
        setInterval(ShowButton, 1000)
}) 


function ShowButton(){
    if(new Date(localStorage.getItem('showAt')) < new Date()){
        const element = document.getElementsByClassName('cta-floating_component')[0]
        element.style.display = 'block';
        element.style.top = '';
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName('cta-floating_component')[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.cta-floating_component {
  position: fixed;
  left: auto;
  top: 9rem;
  right: 2rem;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  max-width: 16rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#b671e4), to(#f01486));
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #b671e4, #f01486);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.cta-floating_close {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  top: -7px;
  right: 0rem;
  bottom: auto;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cta-floating {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta-floating"><div class="cta-floating_component" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; display: block; opacity: 0.9;"><font color="white">Annoucement appears here!</font><div class="cta-floating_close">X<i class="las la-times-circle"></i></div></div></div>
```

Comment: This did the job perfectly. Thanks alot